# Docker fails to start due to "volume store metadata database: timeout"

Tags: docker, centos

I have followed the [installation instructions of Docker CE for CentOS](https://docs.docker.com/engine/installation/linux/centos/). Initially this worked. At some point the system was restarted and now starting Docker fails. Appreciate expert eyes on this matter...

`systemctl start docker` produces:

> Job for docker.service failed because the control process exited with error code. See "systemctl status docker.service" and "journalctl -xe" for details.

`systemctl status docker.service` produces:

```
Apr 21 11:25:23 sec-services-build-1 systemd[1]: Starting Docker Application Container Engine...
Apr 21 11:25:23 sec-services-build-1 dockerd[9693]: time="2017-04-21T11:25:23.370390797+03:00" level=info msg="libcontainerd: previous instance of containerd still alive (8908)"
Apr 21 11:25:23 sec-services-build-1 dockerd[9693]: time="2017-04-21T11:25:23.382492171+03:00" level=warning msg="overlay: the backing xfs filesystem is formatted without d_type support, which leads to incorrect behavior. Reformat the filesystem with ftype=1 to enable d_type support. Running without d_type support will no longer be supported in Docker 17.12."
Apr 21 11:25:23 sec-services-build-1 dockerd[9693]: time="2017-04-21T11:25:23.382547668+03:00" level=info msg="[graphdriver] using prior storage driver: overlay"
Apr 21 11:25:24 sec-services-build-1 dockerd[9693]: Error starting daemon: error while opening volume store metadata database: timeout
Apr 21 11:25:24 sec-services-build-1 systemd[1]: docker.service: main process exited, code=exited, status=1/FAILURE
Apr 21 11:25:24 sec-services-build-1 systemd[1]: Failed to start Docker Application Container Engine.
Apr 21 11:25:24 sec-services-build-1 systemd[1]: Unit docker.service entered failed state.
Apr 21 11:25:24 sec-services-build-1 systemd[1]: docker.service failed.
```

Comment: see also https://github.com/moby/moby/issues/31600  do you share /var/lib/docker between multiple daemons?

Comment: The honest answer is: I don't know. I don't think so... it's a pretty much untouched machine.

Comment: I wouldn't mind even to simply be able to uninstall Docker and reinstall, which didn't work either... sigh.

Answer (score 109, accepted):

From here: https://github.com/moby/moby/issues/22507

I ran:

```
ps axf | grep docker | grep -v grep | awk '{print "kill -9 " $1}' | sudo sh
```

I was then able to restart docker using:

```
sudo systemctl start docker
```

Comment: How to restart docker ?

Comment: @vijay: not sure how you installed it, but I use this: `sudo systemctl start docker`.

Comment: I also had to reboot my machine as there were many defunct processes `[dockerd] <defunct>`

Comment: @vijay To restart docker: `sudo systemctl restart docker`

Comment: See my answer on the ticket to unmount `netns` and `overlayfs` as well as disable autostart on containers while docker is off.

Answer (score 8):

Step 1: systemctl status docker (if docker is running) stop the docker.

step 2: systemctl stop docker.

step 3: dockerd

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 7):

i got this message when copying volumes from production machine, ended up to overwrite `metadata.db` inside `/var/lib/docker/volumes`, then it crashes. A fix is so simple

```sh
docker system prune --volumes -f && rm /var/lib/docker/volumes/metadata.db && docker-compose up -d
```

Comment: removing the folder was enough for me

Answer (score 3):

I encountered the same error.

❶tried

```
sudo kill -9 1452
```

multiple times, but it doesn't work. There's still a `dockerd` process active.

```
 1452 ?        Zsl  127:42 [dockerd] <defunct>
```

❷tried as @Artur Mustafin suggested:

```
sudo mv /var/lib/docker/volumes/metadata.db /var/lib/docker/volumes/metadata.db.bk
```

it worked.

Answer (score 0):

so I tried all of these and nothing worked. However what worked was removing all the containers from /var/lib/docker/containers. Then i killed all docker processes (ps -ef | grep docker) then restarted docker and the docker socket. When docker became active I added the containers one at a time and 1 container was what caused the issues