# Docker stopped all of sudden in CentOS 7

Tags: docker, docker-machine

I was running docker on my CentOS 7 machine.
Today I was trying to upgrade a container. So I stopped the container and tried to pull new image.

I got the below error

```
Error getting v2 registry: Get https://registry-1.docker.io/v2/: proxyconnect tcp: dial tcp: lookup https_proxy=http: no such host"
```

I checked the proxy setting for machine in `cat /etc/environment` and for docker in `cat /etc/systemd/system/docker.service.d/http-proxy.conf`

It is set correctly.
I enabled daemon logs for docker and the logs says

```
Sep 14 10:43:18 myCentOsServer kernel: [4913751.074277] docker0: port 1(veth1e3300a) entered disabled state
Sep 14 10:43:18 myCentOsServer kernel: [4913751.084599] docker0: port 1(veth1e3300a) entered disabled state
Sep 14 10:43:18 myCentOsServer kernel: [4913751.084888] docker0: port 1(veth1e3300a) entered disabled state
Sep 14 10:43:18 myCentOsServer NetworkManager[794]: <info>  [1505349798.0267] device (veth1e3300a): released from master device docker0
Sep 14 10:44:48 myCentOsServer dockerd[29136]: time="2017-09-14T10:44:48.802236300+10:00" level=warning msg="Error getting v2 registry: Get https://registry-1.docker.io/v2/: proxyconnect tcp: dial tcp: lookup https_proxy=http: no such host"
```

I tried below commands but it is stuck.

```
systemctl daemon-reload
systemctl restart docker
```

[image]

Any idea what might be the issue.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: What is the https_proxy set to? It looks like docker can't parse the `//`

Comment: @Matt
The proxy is set as https://uname:pwd@proxyhost:8080/ 
I haven't changed these details.

Comment: Can you try in upercase just for testing, as in https://stackoverflow.com/a/34330377/6309?

Comment: Tried that also now. no luck.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was finally able to solve this issue.
Issue was with my docker mount points.  Mine was set as /var/lib/docker and I suspect it got courrupted when I did data volume export.

**Steps I followed**
1) Navigated to /var/lib/docker, took a backup of images,containers and volumes folder and deleted them.
2) Reloaded the Daemon
3) Restarted the docker.

Now it is working fine.
However bad news is I lost my datadump which I took from one of the containers (using volumes-from).
But it was a dev version of software. So I reinstalled and did the setup.

Answer (score 0):

It occurs sometimes in CentOS. You can simply restart the docker service by

```
systemctl restart docker.service
```

Comment: It won't restart. When I try to, it gets stuck as shown in the image above on my question. I tried restarting machine as well.

Comment: @VVP, then you should try to see log in /var/log/messages, first you can run echo " " > /var/www/messages , and reboot your system then see in your logs that what actually happen in your docker.service.

Comment: 'Sep 14 15:04:35 CentOsHost dockerd[1072]: time="2017-09-14T15:04:35.721024400+10:00" level=info msg="libcontainerd: new containerd process, pid: 1182"
Sep 14 15:04:36 CentOsHost dockerd[1072]: time="2017-09-14T15:04:36.809135800+10:00" level=info msg="[graphdriver] using prior storage driver: overlay"
Sep 14 15:04:37 CentOsHost dockerd[1072]: time="2017-09-14T15:04:37.222375900+10:00" level=info msg="Graph migration to content-addressability took 0.00 seconds"
Sep 14 15:04:37 CentOsHost dockerd[1072]: time="2017-09-14T15:04:37.222861500+10:00" level=info msg="Loading containers: start."'

Comment: `Sep 14 15:04:35 CentOsHost dockerd[1072]: time="2017-09-14T15:04:35.721024400+10:00" level=info msg="libcontainerd: new containerd process, pid: 1182"
Sep 14 15:04:36 CentOsHost dockerd[1072]: time="2017-09-14T15:04:36.809135800+10:00" level=info msg="[graphdriver] using prior storage driver: overlay"
Sep 14 15:04:37 CentOsHost dockerd[1072]: time="2017-09-14T15:04:37.222375900+10:00" level=info msg="Graph migration to content-addressability took 0.00 seconds"
Sep 14 15:04:37 CentOsHost dockerd[1072]: time="2017-09-14T15:04:37.222861500+10:00" level=info msg="Loading containers: start."`

Comment: I followed this [Docker Exception](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43537790/docker-fails-to-start-due-to-volume-store-metadata-database-timeout) 
Now I am seeing this 
`Cannot connect to the Docker daemon at unix:///var/run/docker.sock. Is the docker daemon running?`