# Installation issue on my Jenkins Dockerfile : repository not found

Tags: docker, dockerfile

I wrote the code of dockerfile so it will be easier to install jenkins with all it dependencies and use it for CICD pipeline(i am using docker on windows 10).
this is my code:

```
FROM jenkins/jenkins:lts
USER root

VOLUME /var/run/docker.sock
# install necessary packages to run docker

RUN apt-get -qq -y update && apt-get -qq -y install curl \
&& apt-get -qq -y update  && apt-get -qq -y install sudo  \
&& apt-get -qq -y update  && apt-get -qq -y install  apt-transport-https ca-certificates curl gnupg2 
software-properties-common \
&& apt-get -qq -y update  && apt-get -qq -y install gedit \
&& apt-get -qq -y update  && apt-get -qq -y install maven 3.6.0 \
&& apt-get -qq -y update  && apt-get -qq -y install docker.io \
&& apt-get -qq -y update  && apt-get -qq -y install  build-essential fakeroot dpkg-dev \
&& apt-get -qq -y update  && apt-get -qq -y install  libcurl4-openssl-devpi \
```

My CMD shows this error:"E: The repository 'https://packagecloud.io/github/git-lfs/debian buster Release' does not have a Release file."

Comment: When do you see that error?

Comment: at the "RUN" step

Comment: What is the `libcurl4-openssl-devpi`  package ? I know `libcurl4-openssl-dev`...And why all those `apt-get -qq -y update  && apt-get -qq -y install` onle one is needed at the begining

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You do not need to run `apt-get -qq -y update  && apt-get -qq -y install` after every single installation.
There was also some syntax errors in packages name.
I fixed those.

Here is your Dockerfile after fixing it :

```
FROM jenkins/jenkins:lts
USER root

VOLUME /var/run/docker.sock
# install necessary packages to run docker
RUN apt-get -y update && apt-get -y install curl \
    apt-transport-https ca-certificates curl gnupg2 \
    software-properties-common gedit maven docker.io \
    build-essential fakeroot dpkg-dev \
    libcurl4-openssl-dev

CMD ["sh"] #You do not need this line maybe you have your own default command to run
```

Then just run the command :

`docker build -t <your_docker_username>/<image_name> .`

Comment: i installed the docker image when i run the command "docker version" i get at the bottom "Cannot connect to the Docker daemon at unix:///var/run/docker.sock. Is the docker daemon running?".So i run "dockerd" to run the docker daemon and it gives me "failed to start daemon: error while opening volume store metadata database: timeout
".How can i solve this ?

Comment: On which OS are you runnning ?

Comment: i am running CentOs 7

Comment: what is the output of `groups` ? Are you a member of the `docker` group ?

Comment: i am running as root user

Comment: what's the output of `sudo systemctl status docker`

Comment: run `ps axf | grep docker | grep -v grep | awk '{print "kill -9 " $1}' | sudo sh `  as explained here https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43537790/docker-fails-to-start-due-to-volume-store-metadata-database-timeout

Comment: this is the output @jossefaz ● docker.service - Docker Application Container Engine
   Loaded: loaded (/usr/lib/systemd/system/docker.service; disabled; vendor pres                                                                                        et: disabled)
   Active: active (running) since mar. 2021-04-13 11:59:50 CEST; 24min ago
     Docs: https://docs.docker.com
 Main PID: 17714 (dockerd)
    Tasks: 10
   Memory: 628.2M
   CGroup: /system.slice/docker.service
           └─17714 /usr/bin/dockerd -H fd:// --containerd=/run/containerd/con...

Comment: And you still got the problem ?

Comment: i was stuck in this problem for a period time so now i'm redoing the whole thing will keeep you posted if the problem persists

Answer (score 1):

Using Docker build command

> docker build -t image_name:image_tag path_to_dockerfile

I hope that this can help you to resolve your issue

Comment: i'm already in the folder where the docker file is i ran this command "docker build -t jenkins-docker ." it gets stuck at the last step

Comment: "E: The repository 'https://packagecloud.io/github/git-lfs/debian buster Release' does not have a Release file."

Comment: I think to point to the right position of the error try to separate the different installation using multiple RUN instruction to detect which package cause the error after that to optimize your Dockerfile you can use one RUN instruction , try that and let me know what is the error, thanks.