# Accidently deleted containerd.sock file for docker in Manjaro

Tags: docker, manjaro

while bringing up docker I accidently delete the containterd.sock file in there.
/var/run/docker/containerd/containerd.sock

I uninstalled docker completely and installed it again using pacman

```
sudo pacman -S docker
```

Then I enabled docker

But I still seem to have a problem
on running

```
sudo dockerd
```

here's the error trace

```
error logs WARN[2023-02-23T00:03:36.169211858-06:00] [core] [Channel #1 SubChannel #2] grpc: addrConn.createTransport failed to connect to {
  "Addr": "/var/run/docker/containerd/containerd.sock",
  "ServerName": "localhost",
  "Attributes": {},
  "BalancerAttributes": null,
  "Type": 0,
  "Metadata": null
}. Err: connection error: desc = "transport: error while dialing: dial unix:///var/run/docker/containerd/containerd.sock: timeout"  module=grpc
INFO[2023-02-23T00:03:36.169298390-06:00] [core] [Channel #1 SubChannel #2] Subchannel Connectivity change to TRANSIENT_FAILURE  module=grpc
INFO[2023-02-23T00:03:36.169350352-06:00] [core] [Channel #1] Channel Connectivity change to TRANSIENT_FAILURE  module=grpc
failed to start containerd: timeout waiting for containerd to start
```

Answer (score 0):

Solved the problem by starting up containerd like so

```
sudo containerd
```

This created containerd.sock file elsewhere.
Ran into [Docker fails to start due to "volume store metadata database: timeout"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43537790/docker-fails-to-start-due-to-volume-store-metadata-database-timeout)

Followed the thread and I resolved the problem