Error response from daemon: Get "https://registry-1.docker.io/v2/": proxyconnect tcp: dial tcp: lookup proxy.example.com on 8.8.8.8:53: no such host
The error I got:
pegasus@pegasus:~/Downloads/Docker_deb$ sudo docker run hello-world
Unable to find image 'hello-world:latest' locally
docker: Error response from daemon: Get "https://registry-1.docker.io/v2/": proxyconnect tcp: dial tcp: lookup proxy.example.com on 8.8.8.8:53: no such host.
See 'docker run --help'.

I installed docker using this instructions:

But when I use the following command I get error.
pegasus@pegasus:~/Downloads/Docker_deb$ sudo docker run hello-world
Unable to find image 'hello-world:latest' locally
docker: Error response from daemon: Get "https://registry-1.docker.io/v2/": proxyconnect tcp: dial tcp: lookup proxy.example.com on 8.8.8.8:53: no such host.
See 'docker run --help'.

pegasus@pegasus:~$ sudo dockerd --debug
INFO[2024-06-25T04:10:55.092883645+06:00] Starting up                                  
DEBU[2024-06-25T04:10:55.093453907+06:00] Listener created for HTTP on unix (/var/run/docker.sock) 
DEBU[2024-06-25T04:10:55.110352598+06:00] Golang's threads limit set to 110340         
DEBU[2024-06-25T04:10:55.110827666+06:00] metrics API listening on /var/run/docker/metrics.sock 
DEBU[2024-06-25T04:10:55.113904708+06:00] Using default logging driver json-file       
DEBU[2024-06-25T04:10:55.114060596+06:00] No quota support for local volumes in /var/lib/docker/volumes: Filesystem does not support, or has not enabled quotas 
DEBU[2024-06-25T04:10:55.114096006+06:00] processing event stream                       module=libcontainerd namespace=plugins.moby
DEBU[2024-06-25T04:10:56.076431002+06:00] Cleaning up old mountid : start.             
failed to start daemon: error while opening volume store metadata database (/var/lib/docker/volumes/metadata.db): timeout


how is your instance connected to the internet? is your traffic routing via a proxy?

No I'm not connected to any proxy.
I'm connected using my wifi.

Could you share your proxy configuration in Docker Desktop? Navigate to Settings -> Resources --> Network --> Proxies. I was able to reproduce your issue by setting "proxy.example.com" there as proxy (I set both endpoints - HTTP and HTTPS).

I'm not using Docker Desktop.
I'm using Docker cli

My mistake, I didn't see it was a Linux installation. But still, it seems like your Docker daemon was configured with a proxy. I'm not sure why this happened if you used the default installation procedure.

I'd look into this: Configure the daemon to use a proxy - undo all proxy configuration and restart the daemon.

Why are you starting docker like this: sudo dockerd --debug? You've installed it as a service. You should be running something like sudo systemctl restart docker to restart the service.

I have used that command also

Does this help? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43537790/docker-fails-to-start-due-to-volume-store-metadata-database-timeout

My docker is already running

My issue was solved by taking the following steps:
I removed everything related to docker
for pkg in docker.io docker-doc docker-compose docker-compose-v2 podman-docker containerd runc; do sudo apt-get remove $pkg; done

sudo rm -rf /var/lib/docker/*

sudo apt-get purge docker-ce docker-ce-cli containerd.io docker-buildx-plugin docker-compose-plugin docker-ce-rootless-extras

sudo rm -rf /var/lib/docker
sudo rm -rf /var/lib/containerd

Then installed docker like this:
# Add Docker's official GPG key:
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install ca-certificates curl
sudo install -m 0755 -d /etc/apt/keyrings
sudo curl -fsSL https://download.docker.com/linux/ubuntu/gpg -o /etc/apt/keyrings/docker.asc
sudo chmod a+r /etc/apt/keyrings/docker.asc

# Add the repository to Apt sources:
echo \
  "deb [arch=$(dpkg --print-architecture) signed-by=/etc/apt/keyrings/docker.asc] https://download.docker.com/linux/ubuntu \
  $(. /etc/os-release && echo "$VERSION_CODENAME") stable" | \
  sudo tee /etc/apt/sources.list.d/docker.list > /dev/null
sudo apt-get update

VERSION_STRING=5:26.1.0-1~ubuntu.24.04~noble
sudo apt-get install docker-ce=$VERSION_STRING docker-ce-cli=$VERSION_STRING containerd.io docker-buildx-plugin docker-compose-plugin

sudo snap install docker

docker run hello-world

N.B. You might need to add your user to docker group.

Have a look in the /etc/docker/daemon.json file. The only way i can get docker to replicate this behaviour is to set the following in the daemon.json
root@vps-b21d2eed:/etc/docker# cat daemon.json
{
  "proxies": {
    "http-proxy": "http://proxy.example.com:3128",
    "https-proxy": "https://proxy.example.com:3129",
    "no-proxy": "*.test.example.com,.example.org,127.0.0.0/8"
  }
}

After i restart the docker service I get this error
root@vps-b21d2eed:/etc/docker# docker run -it  hello-world
Unable to find image 'hello-world:latest' locally
docker: Error response from daemon: Get "https://registry-1.docker.io/v2/": proxyconnect tcp: dial tcp: lookup proxy.example.com on 127.0.0.53:53: no such host.
See 'docker run --help'.

if i remove the proxy config in the daemon.json then run sudo systemctl restart docker then it works again

root@vps-b21d2eed:/etc/docker# docker pull hello-world
Using default tag: latest
latest: Pulling from library/hello-world
Digest: sha256:94323f3e5e09a8b9515d74337010375a456c909543e1ff1538f5116d38ab3989
Status: Image is up to date for hello-world:latest
docker.io/library/hello-world:latest


pegasus@pegasus:~$  cat /etc/docker/daemon.json
cat: /etc/docker/daemon.json: No such file or directory



Maybe have a read in https://docs.docker.com/reference/cli/dockerd/#proxy-configuration is your docker daemon is trying to use a proxy to reach the registry, and it looks like its using a default example proxy

I've added the dockerd output above

when I run sudo run hello-world it gives the following output. docker: Cannot connect to the Docker daemon at unix:///var/run/docker.sock. Is the docker daemon running?.

+1 This seems like the proper answer to the original question. But I fear that editing Docker config and restarting the Docker daemon can be a wonderful source of new errors for someone who's attempting a simple Docker install for the first time. ^^
